# Zxing in android always in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm trying to implement a barcode reader.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfucGSKngq4&list=PLYBH5YZZegIf1DzLtuFmeDFqHYsfw1h1I&index=7&t=232s
I've followed this tutorial, and almost everything works fine. The only issue I have is that it always opens in landscape screen, and I have absolutely no clue what I do wrong.

```
butonScanare.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
        integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivity.class);
        integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scanare");
        integrator.initiateScan();
    });
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
   <activity
            android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"/>
```